# Saída do comando echo com % e %%

Tags: bash, shell-script

Ao resolver alguns exercícios em Shell Script, encontro este script:

```
x="Este texto para teste."
echo ${x% *}
```

Confesso que, ao realizar o teste de mesa, não consegui resolvê-lo. Ao rodar este script o resultado foi:

```
Este texto para
```

Entretanto se modificar o echo para `echo ${x%% *}`, o resultado será:

```
Este
```

Qual é a explicação para estes resultados, tanto com `%` quanto com `%%`? Existe algum uso prático nestas expressões ou sua ênfase é somente em  exercícios didáticos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas são apenas duas das [muitas formas de se manipular strings em Bash](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). No caso, ambas servem para remover um trecho do final de uma string.

A diferença é que `%` remove o menor trecho possível, enquanto `%%` remove o maior trecho possível. Por exemplo, se eu tiver:

```
texto='abcdefbxyz'
```

E fizer:

```
echo ${texto%b*z}
```

Ele vai remover o menor trecho do final da string que corresponde a `b*z` (a letra `b`, zero ou mais caracteres e a letra `z`). O menor trecho que satisfaz essa condição é `bxyz`, por isso resultado deste `echo` é `abcdef`.

Agora se eu fizer:

```
echo ${texto%%b*z}
```

Ele vai remover o maior trecho do final da string que corresponde a `b*z` (a letra `b`, zero ou mais caracteres e a letra `z`). O maior trecho que satisfaz essa condição é `bcdefbxyz`, por isso resultado deste `echo` é `a`.

---

No seu caso, a string é `"Este texto para teste."`. Ao fazer `echo ${x% *}`, ele remove o menor trecho do final da string que corresponde a um espaço seguido de zero ou mais caracteres. O trecho que satisfaz esta condição é  `teste.`, por isso o resultado é `Este texto para`.

E o fazer `echo ${x%% *}`, ele remove o maior trecho do final da string que corresponde a um espaço seguido de zero ou mais caracteres. O trecho que satisfaz esta condição é  `texto para teste.`, por isso o resultado é `Este`.

É um recurso bem útil (para qualquer situação que envolva remover um trecho final de uma string), muito longe de ser algo "somente para exercícios".

Na documentação [tem alguns exemplos](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html#CVT).

Comment: Obrigado! Ótima síntese, ao ler a  segunda linha já consegui compreender!